# i am trying to scrape website using selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

How could i get all the categories mentioned on each listing page of the same website i.e. code as well as title i am trying to scrape website through selenium and using beautiful soup to scrape each page

here i am trying to scrape each page from website and append it to dataframe  as df1

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Code', 'Title'])

    x = driver.get("https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=%27")
    
    while True:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
            right_table = soup.find('table', id="dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView")
            #df = pd.read_html(str(right_table))[0]
            df = pd.read_html(str(right_table))[0]
            # Clean up the DataFrame
            df = df[[0, 1]]
            df.columns = df.iloc[0]
            df = df[1:]
            print(df)
            df1.append(df, ignore_index = True)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@id, 'UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView')]//tr[last()]//table//span//following::a[1]"))).click()
            print("Clicked for next page")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more pages")
            break
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So his code looks a bit incomplete, though if I'm correct this portion looks like you're using Selenium here.

Particularly, the following line:

```
x = driver.get("https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27=%27")
```

This will open the website in a browser. Which is fine, but then later you try and pass this browser object to BeautifulSoup, which is not fine, here:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
```

BeautifulSoup is expecting to consume XHTML/the webpage sourcecode.

So in this case if you are going to do that you can get the source code of webpage from Selenium by making **x** -> **x.page_source**:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x.page_source, 'lxml')
```

(Further I would consider do you really need to be using Selenium for this? A quick perusal of the website it might just work with pure Requests module.....)